# Adding Service Reference to a .cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, service, reference

I have a generic .cs class file that I use for generic tasks between different programs.  I have recently started using a Service Reference which works fine with other .aspx.cs files within my code, but not in my .cs file.

It says I am missing a reference whenever I try to add the code to my .cs file.

How would I go about putting this service reference into my class?

Comment: What you are doing is unclear; you add references to _projects_, not _files_.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your service reference to your project. Once you have a new reference you can use a client from the added namespace to call the service.